# StopIteration: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL error

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, python-imaging-library

```python
import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                            'E:/Python/A-
                      Z/Convolutional_Neural_Networks/dataset/training_set',
                                            target_size=(64, 64),
                                            batch_size=32,
                                            class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                        'E:/Python/A-
                          Z/Convolutional_Neural_Networks/dataset/test_set',
                                        target_size=(64, 64),
                                        batch_size=32,
                                        class_mode='binary')

classifier.fit_generator(
                training_set,
                steps_per_epoch=8000,
                epochs=25,
                validation_data=test_set,
                validation_steps=2000)
```

please help I am a beginner in this CNN I am using keras to program the task but I am getting the above error(given in the title)
I have tried installing and then uninstalling pillow
but nothing working it is showing the same error I have also tried some other StackOverflow answers but they are also not working

Comment: import sys
    from PIL import Image
    sys.modules['Image'] = Image 
    from PIL import Image
    print(Image.__file__)
    import Image
   print(Image.__file__)

Comment: both have same path

Comment: Did you create any environment to install keras?? Are you intalling pillow in the "same" environment?

Comment: yes actually it is fixed now I was using python 3.6 and 3.5 fixed it now it is showing no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came the same error as you.
this is my environment:
I create "tensorflow" env in anaconda, python 3.6 kernel,activate the env, then

```
pip install tensorflow

pip install keras

pip install pillow
```

and the error was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  If you are using Anaconda and the Jupyter notebook this is what worked for me.

Close your notebook and stop Jupyter.
Exit out of your environment
Restart the environment again and run:

**pip install pillow**

and then:

**pip install jupyterlab**

and start jupyter-notebook back up and then add or (re-run):

**from PIL import Image**

In your notebook and hopefully .fit_generator will no longer throw that error.

Answer (score 0):

The following is applicable to Windows users working with Anaconda:
If you've installed 'tensorflow' with pip, or a pip variant (ie. pip3), then you will have to install tensorflow again, but this time with the command `conda install tensorflow`.