# How to solve 'array_to_img' requires PIL error in py_call_impl using RStudio and Keras

Tags: r, keras, anaconda, rstudio

I've been following the guide here: https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2017-12-14-image-classification-on-small-datasets/ about how to set up CNNs in Keras, and my code fails at this line:

```
history <- model %>% fit_generator(
  train_generator,
  steps_per_epoch = 100,
  epochs = 30,
  validation_data = validation_generator,
  validation_steps = 50
)
```

with the following error:

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
>     ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL.

Here are the results of reticulate::py_config():

```
python:         C:\Users\Trent\Anaconda3\envs\r-tensorflow\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/Trent/Anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\Trent\ANACON~2\envs\R-TENS~1
version:        3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Feb 21 2019, 18:30:04) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\Users\Trent\ANACON~2\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.16.2
keras:          C:\Users\Trent\ANACON~2\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.p

python versions found: 
 C:\Users\Trent\Anaconda3\envs\r-tensorflow\python.exe
 C:\Users\Trent\ANACON~2\python.exe
 C:\Users\Trent\Anaconda3\python.exe
 C:\Users\Trent\Anaconda3\envs\pillow\python.exe
```

I've never written any python, so I'm not exactly sure how to solve this problem using the backend methods I've seen described on stackOverflow in the past, but I did try.

*I tried following the advice here: 
[StopIteration: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49196602/stopiteration-could-not-import-pil-image-the-use-of-array-to-img-requires-pi) and opened up the anaconda prompt and typed in the following lines:

> conda activate r-tensorflow

Then the screen crashes after some text pops on screen (it's too fast to read). In order to avoid this I tried to just do the following:

> conda install r-tensorflow pillow

Then it says # All requested packages already installed.

- I've updated R and all of its packages.
- I've also uninstalled all of anaconda and reinstalled the newest version.
- I've also rerun install_keras() with and without the GPU option to try and get it to work (I couldn't get the GPU part to work for the h5py error so I stopped looking at that one since online it says that the CPU version should be easier to work with)
- The thread here: https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/216 suggests that I should open the anaconda prompt and type in the following:

> conda install -c conda-forge pillow

I've modified this to include my environment since I couldn't activate it to read as the following:

> conda install -c r-tensorflow conda-forge pillow

but I couldn't get it to read what I meant.

- Lots of things say to use pip install pillow but since I don't know how to activate the right environment I'm really not sure how to do that. I've tried

> conda install r-tensorflow pillow

with no success so I'm not exactly sure how to do it with pip but would be happy to test it with someone's help.

```
history <- model %>% fit_generator(
  train_generator,
  steps_per_epoch = 100,
  epochs = 30,
  validation_data = validation_generator,
  validation_steps = 50
)
```

I expected the training to begin after I ran the above line but unfortunately I just get the error.

I would be happy to provide more detail as it is needed and thank you all so much for your help in advance.

Comment: So I think I have more information about this. I picked it up again today to try and run it after updating the packages, hoping there had been a fix. To my surprise, I ran the example I had typed up from above https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2017-12-14-image-classification-on-small-datasets/ and the line that had been failing for me suddenly worked!

I quickly stopped R and activated the notebook that had the code for my own project and it failed again. I reran my example and it failed too. After stopping it and having R crash, I ran it again and it worked again only once.